# Transform operator on type `t` to operator on type `a->t`

Tags: haskell

Is this a standard way to transform operator on type `t` to operator on type `a->t`? I.e., is this a lib implementing this function (`fT` like `functionTransformer`):

```
fT :: (t -> t -> t) -> (a -> t) -> (a -> t) -> (a -> t)
fT op f1 f2 = \x -> (f1 x) `op` (f2 x)
```

(we could generalize to `fT :: (t1 -> t2 -> t) -> (t3 -> t1) -> (t3 -> t2) -> t3 -> t`)

I was asking this question when learning Yesod: in this framework, we can add a validation condition for a field thanks to `checkBool`. For instance, I can create a field which only accepts value greater thant 100 with:

```
smallIntField = checkBool (<= 100) "error: this entry has to be smaller than 100" intField
```

Thanks to my "function transformer", I can easily manage bounded value with:

```
($&&) = fT (&&)
boundedIntField = checkBool ((>= 0) $&& (<= 100)) "error: this entry has to be between 0 and 100" intField
```

Comment: is it only me or is your *signature* off - either `op :: t -> t -> t` or you even `fT :: (t1 -> t2 -> t) -> (t3 -> t1) -> (t3 -> t2) -> t3 -> t` (says ghci) ;)

Comment: Is `on` from `Data.Function` what you're looking for?

Comment: @CarstenKönig indeed... I've edited my post.
@Mokosha not exactly, with `on`, there is only one `f`, in my case there is `f1` and `f2`.

Comment: but now your signature is even more off (`>= 0)` surely is not of type `bool -> bool` - let me help you out ;)

Comment: I think what you really want is `liftA2` or `liftM2` on `&&`, so `(<&&>) = liftM2 (&&)` then you can use it as `(>=0) <&&> (<= 100)`, etc.  This has the added benefit of working on any applicative or monad, not just the function applicative or monad (which is what we take advantage of here).  It'd probably be best to define it using `liftA2` because this is less restrictive than `liftM2`, but you probably won't come across any problems from using `liftM2` often.

Comment: @bheklilr you should make this into an answer

Comment: Thinking about it here the idea in Yesod is probably to just use `(.)` and multiple `checkBool` (or other Validation) or just use an point-full lambda (I would do) - most of this fancier point-free stuff is just a bit to hard to read/remember for my taste - although @bheklilr solution seem reasonable nice ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're really looking for is the `liftA2` or `liftM2` combinators (from `Control.Applicative` or `Control.Monad` respectively).  `liftM2` is going to work the same as `liftA2` since all monads are applicatives, but it's up to you if you want to be more or less restrictive.  Using the monadic implementation will also force order of evaluation of the arguments, which can't be guaranteed by `liftA2`.

You can use it as

```
(<&&>) :: Applicative f => f Bool -> f Bool -> f Bool
(<&&>) = liftA2 (&&)
```

For functions like `(>= 0)` or `(<= 100)`, The `Applicative f => f` gets specialized to `(Ord a, Num a) => (->) a`, so the type signature would be

```
(<&&>) :: (Ord a, Num a) => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
```

So you could write something like

```
between :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
between lower upper = (lower <=) <&&> (<= upper)
```

If you defined `<||> = liftM2 (||)` then you could even do something more complicated like

```
between 0 100 <||> between 200 400 <||> (>= 1000) :: Int -> Bool
```

Which would check if the number is an element of `[0, 100] U [200, 400] U [1000, inf)` if we were writing this in set notation (`U` is set union).

Answer (score 2):

This code is in the `Control.Applicative` module:

```
instance Applicative ((->) r) where
    pure a = \_ -> a
    ff <*> fa = \r -> ff r (fa r)

liftA2 :: Applicative f => f (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
liftA2 f fa fb = pure f <*> fa <*> fb
```

Your `fT` function is just what we get when we take `liftA2` and use `(->) a` for `f`, and `t` for `a`, `b` and `c`.  We can rewrite your function just like this:

```
fT :: (t -> t -> t) -> (a -> t) -> (a -> t) -> (a -> t)
fT = liftA2
```

By substitution, we can prove it's the same as yours:

```
liftA2 op f1 f2
    = (pure op <*> f1) <*> f2
    = \a -> (pure op <*> f1) a (f2 a)
    = \a -> (\a -> pure op a (fa 1)) a (f2 a)
    = \a -> (\a -> (\_ -> op) a (f1 a)) a (f2 a)
    = \a -> (\a -> op (f1 a)) a (f2 a)
    = \a -> op (f1 a) (f2 a)
    = \a -> (f1 a) `op` (f2 a)
```